# Permeability: is webers per ampere-turn meter (Wb / At.m) equivalent to henrys per meter (H / m)?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

Is webers per ampere-turn meter equal to henries per meter?

*I.e.* is \$\frac{Wb}{At.m}\$ equal to \$\frac{H}{m}\$?

-and if so, is there an easy way to picture the equivalence?

Comment: Do the units match, check the dimensions of each part. hint take each term to the basic SI units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of [inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance) per turn is total flux per amp of current: -

$$L = \dfrac{\Phi}{I}$$

Dividing both sides by length, d gives equivalence for a one turn winding: -

$$\dfrac{L}{d} = \dfrac{\Phi}{I\cdot d}$$